# Custom Type Deserialize to 'object' results in extra curly brackets

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a class like this:

```
class Document
{
    public string id {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
}

var doc = new Document() { id= "1", name = "Doc1" };
var docs = new List<Document>() { doc };
```

...

I am sending docs through HTTP post to my backend service.

In my controller, I am receiving it as List docs.

The reason for this is, I want to use one controller to accept any Custom Types.

The trouble is, that, each item in List docs are wrapped inside extra curly braces

```
"{{\"id\":\"1\", \"name\":\"Doc1\"}}"
```

1. How to prevent extra curly braces? Can it be prevented?
2. If cannot be prevented, is there a way to extra the object removing the extra "{" and "}" ?

Comment: @stuartd I've removed the outer quotes and changed \" back to " (I suspect the OP had copied text directly from a Visual Studio watch window rather than the unencoded text).  Just waiting for change to be approved.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh i also think so, since c# lang has a special meaning for braces {}, its showing {{ to represent {, are you getting this Junilo? His confusion is related to string but strings themselves is not why he is not being able to deserialize it, its the deserialization code, maybe some cast is wrong or the class definition is wrong. Basically there are no extra braces inside the string, he should verify (for his own clarity) first/second character of the string like str[0] and str[1] in immediate window.

Comment: Sorry to confuse you guys with wrong deserialised output. I am actually seeing: [{{\"id\":\"1\", \"name\":\"Doc1\"}}] notice the "{{" and "}}". I expected it to be just [{\"id\":\"1\", \"name\":\"Doc1\"}]

Comment: @Junilo: Change the question instead of posting code in a comment.

Comment: What is the code you are using to post to your backend service?  In other words, what is creating the JSON?  That is where I would look for the problem.

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is something called Newtonsoft.Json. It has whole lot of methods like `Serialize` and `Deserialize` objects. Check the [link](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json). Specially when you are sending values to the Api, The Api should accept the same thing as you are sending. If you are sending List then Api should accept same class List in its parameter.
If you are receiving some result from the API/you are consuming the API you should deserialize the string received in result.
To do this you can use -:

- JObject,JToken
- Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.Deserialize

Answer (score 0):

The actual output of serializing the list of documents would be:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Doc1"}]
```

The outer `[]` is an array, and each object inside `{id: number, name: string}` is your document.

```
    var doc = new Document { id = "1", name = "Doc1" };
    var docs = new List<Document> { doc };
    var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(docs);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: I wanted to receive the JSON as List<object> in the Api controller, not List<Document>. The reason for this is so that I can send any Custom Types and just receive them as List<object> and with this, I am having this extra curly braces. So yes, I am seeing [{{\"id\":\"1", \"name\":\"Doc1\"}}]. I think there is no way we can prevent the extra "{" and "}" because I am receiving the list not using the source Custom Type but using object instead?

Comment: If you don't box the Document in an object before you serialize it, you can treat it as a plain `object` when you deserialize it.